# What's the best way to redirect a URL when developing on localhost?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, localhost, redirect

**Problem:**

I have two web apps, and "App1" fetches data from "App2" via ajax.In production, App1 should fetch data from the production url for App2. However, when I'm developing App1 on localhost:3000, I want App1 to be fetching data from the local version of App2 at localhost:3001 (not from the production version).

**Prior Research:**

I've searched around a lot for how to do this, but can't really make heads or tails of the stuff I've found.

- I've read some things suggesting I should change /etc/hosts, but I haven't been able to get that working because the production site uses HTTPS but my localhost is only HTTP.
- I've also come across .htaccess, but adding the file didn't seem to have any effect, and I get pretty lost in the Apache rabbit hole, just looking for how to turn the .htaccess stuff on. (I've seen some stuff about mod-rewrite too, but can't figure out how to get that working either.)
- I've also discovered Chrome extensions like the [Switcheroo Redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg?hl=en), but this hasn't worked well because simple redirects change some essential HTTP responses to 301, which my app isn't designed to handle.

**Questions**

- What's the right tool for what I'm trying to do? (/etc/hosts, .htaccess, or something else)
- What's the most basic configuration of that tool to get the desired result?

Comment: You somehow have to change the URL actually requested by app1. No way around that. Typically such a URL (at least the base URL) is a configuration parameter of an app, not hard coded in the path. So you could place it in a configuration file, or, more elegant, hand it over as environment variable from http server to the php script. Then, and only then you have available all means of rewriting you want. But without that the requests won't even reach your local http server which means all attempts to do anything simply have no effect.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, one option would indeed be modifying the local host name configuration to resolve that production system name to the local address. Then you'd have to configure a virtual host in your local http server with the production systems name locally and turn on https with a self signed certificate. That should work, only your app needs to accept such a self signed certificate for https connections, so certificate validation should be switched off.

Comment: Also, @arkascha if you copy your response as an answer (not a comment) I can accept  it and close this question.

Comment: Not sure if that already solves your issue. That is why I made it a comment ;-)

Comment: I was imagining a different solution, but the one you described solves my problem so I figure it's just fine 

Comment: Ok, as you like. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Typically you somehow want to change the URL actually requested by app1. Usually such a URL (at least a base URL) is a configuration parameter of an app, not hard coded. So you could place it in a configuration file, or, more elegant, hand it over as environment variable from http server to the php script. Then, and only then you have available all means of rewriting you want. But without that the requests won't even reach your local http server which means all attempts to do anything simply have no effect.

One other option would however be to modify the local host name configuration to resolve that app2 production systems name to the local ip address. Then you'd have to configure a virtual host inside your local http server with the production systems name and turn on https. You can use a a self signed certificate for the ssl encryption. That should work, only your app needs to accept such a self signed certificate for https connections, so certificate validation should be switched off.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a simple request with jquery like the following. See more information of query Ajax request with query http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
var url = "localhost:3001/cart/1";
 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: currentQueryData,
            success: function(data) {
              console.log("Data from App2 url: + data);
              // Do something with your data
            },
            failure: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

And when you go with your developed Apps to production simply change the value of the property url to "https://api.app2.com" So that the request goes than to the production App2. 
You can also point the production urls to your localhost by editing the /etc/hosts configuration file and add this line to it:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.app2.de
```

But you need still to add the Port to that domain in your javascript file. Like

```
var url = "domain.app2.de:3001"
```

Because you can not bind a domain to specific port in the /etc/hosts file. 
So something like the following doesn't work!

```
127.0.0.1:3001 domain.app2.de  # not working
```

Hope it helps. I would recommend to store the entry point url to your app2 in an configuration too. To store it in a javascript value is just for showing the purpose of how to get it done as siplefied example. Otherwise would be great if you can provide an example what you want to fetch from the app2.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `mod_proxy` + `mod_rewrite` such that all URLs with a single path prefix on the main domain are rewritten internally into a proxy request to app2. This has several advantages:

1. You don't contaminate your front-end with server config. This gives a good separation of concerns and ensures the code does not differ between dev and live.
2. No CORS issues because, to the client, all requests are sent to the same scheme, domain and port.
3. Ajax URLs are cleaner since they can just be root-relative. (As should be all your URLs.)
4. You can use the same, unmodified `.htaccess` file on dev and live servers because it can conditionally rewrite to each app2 based on the host header sent. (Though you should really be putting config in your vhost if you have access to it.)
5. You can use the same conditional logic to only enforce https on live. (Don't do it in app code.)
6. You can switch to different app2 servers for relocations/upgrades by editing a single rule, without any interruption to the users.

Assuming you do this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
# force https and single domain on live
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!real-app1\.com$). [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+/(\S*)
RewriteRule ^ https://real-app1.com/%1 [NS,NE,L,R=301]
# API proxy on dev
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+/API(?:/(\S*))?
RewriteRule ^API(?:$|/) http://localhost:3001/%1 [NS,NE,P]
# API proxy on live (no need for hostname check)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+/API(?:/(\S*))?
RewriteRule ^API(?:$|/) https://real-app2.com/%1 [NS,NE,P]
```

Then, in your front-end, normal links can just be `<a href="/foo/bar/">…` and, assuming you're using a library, ajax can be as easy as this:

```
$.ajax('/API/path/to/endpoint/', {
    data: {
        query_param: 'param_value'
    }
})
.done(function() {
    // API works
})
.fail(function() {
    // oh dear
});
```

There, app2 should receive `http://localhost:3001/path/to/endpoint/?query_param=param_value`. The amount of work to set this up properly is less than the headache of managing config and deployment issues for the life of the apps. Definitely worth it.